# Extract climate data

Tags: qgis, export, climate

I need Qgis to extract climate data informations which are layered into the maps. Moreoever, I got exact geospatial plot-information for all of the plots.
So lets say I got in QGIS a map with 2500 plot-points, which are already named, from each of which Qgis can give me the desired value information (say Point 1322: 14,2 T°c/year ). The identifaction tool seems to work only per point, when I try to select the whole area QGis wont give me any informations whatsoever.
How can I export the values linked to points?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I solved it:
I first needed to reproject the layers, since point and raster data were somehow based on different WGS. The add-on "Point sampling tool" then let me merge the informations from the raster file with the point-plot-informations. So now I got my desired climate information for each point.